# <audio></audio>, IE8 and "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, audio, internet-explorer-8

I have some code to play sounds on the page, and it works with every browser, but IE8.

```
<audio id="myaudio" style="display:none;"></audio>
<script>
    myaudio=document.getElementByID('myaudio');
    myaudio.src='path/to/wav/mywav.wav';
</script>
```

which works fine for all tested browsers and plays file, everything works fine. All browsers, except IE8.
IE8 debugger says "Object doesn't support this property or method" on         `myaudio=document.getElementByID('myaudio');`.

Can't figure out how to fix that.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support HTML5 tags like `audio` afaik.

Comment: You have to use an alternative approach to support IE8. Sorry.

Comment: document.getElementByID should not work in any browser, because it has a lowercase `d` at the end (& javascript is case-sensitive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML `<audio>` tag is a HTML 5 feature not supported in Internet Explorer until version 9. Hence why it does not work in verson 8.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp